# Preg_replace finds a match where there shouldn't be one

Tags: php, regex

So I'm doing my own simple Markdown formatter. I'm fixing the last of the issues when I ran into an issue with my code block formatter. For some reason it matches an extra time where there shouldn't be anything to match.

````php
$matches = [
    "```\ncode block \n```",
    "code block \n"
];

private function code_block_format($matches): string
    {
        // get a line
        $regex = '/([^\n]*)\n?/';
        // wrap that line into <code> elem + new line
        $repl = '<code>$1</code>' . "\n";
        // remove trailing linebreaks + spaces
        $matches[1] = trim($matches[1]);
        $ret = preg_replace($regex, $repl, $matches[1]); // this returns the badly formatted string
        $ret = "<pre>\n" . $ret . "</pre>";
        return $ret;
    }
````

The preg_replace just return `<code>code block</code>\n` but for some reason I get an extra element `<code>code block</code>\n<code></code>\n`

Any help on what in the world could be causing it to latch onto a "" string somewhere in there?

**Edit**

My goal is to make a codeblock element similar to what you can write here where there can be empty lines between the ``` tags, so lines with simply \n should be matched as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got an idea from the answers and found the regex I works as I want. `([^\n]+\n?|\n)` allows me to capture a line with text or the empty lines as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`$regex = '/([^\n]*)\n?/';` returns strings that do not contain `\n` zero or more times, so basically everything.

Change `*` to `+`, which means it occurs one or more times.

`$regex = '/([^\n]+)\n?/';`

I actually can't figure out exactly why `*` is returning the second group. `/[^a]*/g` returns two groups for any text that doesn't include an `a`, and I would expect one.

Although, your code seems needlessly complex. Are you just trying to remove white space from $match[1] with trim(), then surround it with `<code></code>`?

You can just concatenate the tags onto the trimmed $matches[1]:

`return '<code>' . $matches[1] . '</code';`

Comment: It is for multiline codeblock, where each line is wrapped in <code> tags, which is supposed to allow empty line in between text lines too. The trim is to remove the leading and trailing linebreaks, and possible spaces to reduce the possibility of the empty lines it could match from before the actual text

Comment: This is a helper function called via `preg_replace_callback` and the contents of $matches[1] is everything between the \``` tags

Answer (score 0):

You can try this since your initial is ZERO or more matches and can create a group where there is just a newline...

```
$regex = '/([^\n]+)\n?/';
```

It should output:

```
<pre>
<code>code block</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: But i want to allow for newlines in between text lines